# Using a closure vs a method within a view that takes in a closure

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I've been using SwiftLint and ran into multiple `multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure` errors defined [here](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure.html).

The biggest issue I had was my `Button` where I would toggle some boolean value, e.g.

```swift
Button(action: {self.startTimer.toggle()}) {
   ...trailing closure
}
```

When I switched out the short hand closure for a method

```swift
func toggleTimer() { self.startTimer.toggle() }
```

the linting error disappeared. I'm still not sure what the complaint was in terms of the "more than one closure argument" part.

*Trailing closure syntax should not be used when passing more than one closure argument.*

What is meant by this linting error in this particular example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button expects two closures, one for "action" and one for "label".  SwiftLint doesn't like you to leave off the label that sits in between the two closures.  It is expecting this:

```
   Button(action: {self.startTimer.toggle()}, label: {
           ...trailing closure
        })
```

Your code is perfectly valid, it is just not formatted to the specs of SwiftLint.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this extended explanation